# php preg match a-zA-Z and only one space between 2 or more words

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

For my PHP script I have this code:

```
if (!preg_match("/[^A-Za-z]/", $usersurname))
   $usersurname_valid = 1;
```

This worked untill I realized a surname can be two or more words... *doh*.

Anyone can tell me how to write this code if I want to allow 1 space between two worlds? For example:

Jan Klaas is now wrong and Jan Klaas should be allowed, also Jan Klaas Martijn and so on should be allowed.
Even better would be a preg replace, to replace two or more spaces with 1, so when you write:
 Jan(space)(space)Klaas or Jan(space)(space)(space)(space)Klaas, it would return Jan(space)Klaas.

I searched around for a while but somehow I just can't get this space matching to work..

PS: When I got this working, I will apply this for the mid and last name too ofcourse.

===========================================

**EDIT:** After you helping me out, I re-wrote my code to:

```
// validate usersurname
$usersurname = preg_replace("/\s{2,}/"," ", $usersurname);
if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z]+(\s[A-Za-z]+)*$/",$usersurname))
    $usersurname_valid = 1; 
// validate usermidname
$usermidname = preg_replace("/\s{2,}/"," ", $usermidname);
if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z]+(\s[A-Za-z]+)*$/",$usermidname))
    $usermidname_valid = 1;
// validate userforename
$userforename = preg_replace("/\s{2,}/"," ", $userforename);
if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z]+(\s[A-Za-z]+)*$/",$userforename))
    $userforename_valid = 1;
```

and the error notifications

```
elseif ($usersurname_valid !=1)
    echo ("<p id='notification'>Only alphabetic character are allowed for the last name. $usersurname $usermidname $userforename</p>");
// usermidname character validation
elseif ($usermidname_valid !=1)
    echo ("<p id='notification'>Only alphabetic character are allowed for the middle name. $usersurname $usermidname $userforename</p>");
// userforename character validation
elseif ($userforename_valid !=1)
    echo ("<p id='notification'>Only alphabetic character are allowed for the (EDIT) first name. $usersurname $usermidname $userforename</p>");
```

Replacing the spaces are working well and I need this preg_match to check on on A-Za-z + space. I think in this case it doesn't matter if it's matching more than 1 spaces because it's replaced anyway, right?

**EDIT:**

Solution for my case:

```
$usersurname = preg_replace("/\s{2,}/"," ", $usersurname);
if (!preg_match("/[^A-Za-z ]/", $usersurname))
```

This does the work. Thanks for helping out, J0HN

Comment: Sample usernames that fail the regex, please. :)

Comment: Serbian and Dutch. Do you? Since nothing fails the regex, there's notmuch to sample, is there?

Comment: Yes, Ivan is rather popular name in Russia, so I thought we could simplify our conversation. :) Ok, so, what's the problem than? Does regex allows to much, or restricts to much? I mean, does it fail valid names, or pass invalid?

Comment: Oh I though you were taunting. Sorry my bad. Did you see my answer? I tested it with all kind of entries, special chars, spaces and diff words, it works, and I think it should work too.

Comment: So, the problem is solved? :) If so, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, solving the problem you have in mind:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z]+(\s[A-Za-z]+)*$/",$usersurname)) { ... }
```

But, well, it's just a part of the solution, and it's not bulletproof. Look at the [list of common mistakes](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) when handling names.

So, you'd better to re-think on your validation approach.

Replacing the multiple spaces is simpler to achieve as a separate instruction, something like

```
$processed_usersurname = preg_replace("/\s{2,}/"," ", $usersurname);
```

This will match and replace any two or more consequent whitespace characters (space, tab, linebreak and carriage return) to single space

Comment: Are you sure? I still get the error 

`($usersurname_valid !=1)
       echo ("<p id='notification'>Only alphabetic character are allowed for the first, middle and last name.</p>");`

Comment: Updated the answer, missed the pluses and line boundaries. Btw, there are a nice tool to quickly validate regexes: http://regexpal.com/

Comment: Thank you. The space replacement works, but the preg match still doens't wanna co-operate

Comment: Post the code. Also, consider inspecting `$usersurname` just before passing it to `preg_match` and evaluating it against the regex in regexpal. Also, try examining the return value of preg_match. You are implicitly converting int to boolean, it shouldn't be a problem, but just to avoid some stupid mistakes...